# Hadoop MapReduce reducer does not start

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, reduce

The map phase runs and then just quits without bothering with the reducer. The job alternately prints "Hello from mapper." and "Writing CellWithTotalAmount" and that's it. The output directory it creates is empty.

I've checked at least a dozen of other "reducer won't start" questions and have not found an answer. I've checked that the output of map is the same as input into reduce, that reduce uses Iterable, that correct output classes have been set, etc.

**Job config**

```
public class HoursJob {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 2) {
          System.err.println("Usage: HoursJob <input path> <output path>");
          System.exit(-1);
        }

        Job job = Job.getInstance();
        job.setJarByClass(HoursJob.class);
        job.setJobName("Hours job");

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.setMapperClass(HoursMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(HoursReducer.class);

        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(CellWithTotalAmount.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);

        int ret = job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
        System.exit(ret);
    }
}
```

**Mapper**

```
public class HoursMapper 
        extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, IntWritable, CellWithTotalAmount> {
    static double BEGIN_LONG = -74.913585;
    static double BEGIN_LAT = 41.474937;
    static double GRID_LENGTH = 0.011972;
    static double GRID_HEIGHT = 0.008983112;

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Mapper.Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        System.out.println("Hello from mapper.");
        String recordString = value.toString();
        try {
            DEBSFullRecord record = new DEBSFullRecord(recordString);
            Date pickupDate = record.getPickup();
            Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(pickupDate);
            int pickupHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int cellX = (int)
                ((record.getPickupLongitude() - BEGIN_LONG) / GRID_LENGTH) + 1;
            int cellY = (int)
                ((BEGIN_LAT - record.getPickupLatitude()) / GRID_HEIGHT) + 1;

            CellWithTotalAmount hourInfo = 
                new CellWithTotalAmount(cellX, cellY, record.getTotal());
            context.write(new IntWritable(pickupHour), hourInfo);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Cannot parse: " + recordString + "due to the " + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**Reducer**

```
public class HoursReducer 
        extends Reducer<IntWritable, CellWithTotalAmount, Text, NullWritable> {
    @Override
    public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<CellWithTotalAmount> values, 
            Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Hello from reducer.");
        int[][] cellRideCounters = getCellRideCounters(values);
        CellWithRideCount cellWithMostRides = 
            getCellWithMostRides(cellRideCounters);

        int[][] cellTotals = getCellTotals(values);
        CellWithTotalAmount cellWithGreatestTotal = 
            getCellWithGreatestTotal(cellTotals);

        String output = key + " "
            + cellWithMostRides.toString() + " "
            + cellWithGreatestTotal.toString();

        context.write(new Text(output), NullWritable.get());
    }

    //omitted for brevity
}
```

**Custom writable class**

```
public class CellWithTotalAmount implements Writable {
    public int cellX;
    public int cellY;
    public double totalAmount;

    public CellWithTotalAmount(int cellX, int cellY, double totalAmount) {
        this.cellX = cellX;
        this.cellY = cellY;
        this.totalAmount = totalAmount;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Writing CellWithTotalAmount");
        out.writeInt(cellX);
        out.writeInt(cellY);
        out.writeDouble(totalAmount);
    }

    @Override
    public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Reading CellWithTotalAmount");
        cellX = in.readInt();
        cellY = in.readInt();
        totalAmount = in.readDouble();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return cellX + " " + cellY + " " + totalAmount;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a lot of exception in reduce function so Framework can not complete the job properly

```
    public class HoursReducer 
            extends Reducer<IntWritable, CellWithTotalAmount, Text, NullWritable> {
        @Override
        public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<CellWithTotalAmount> values, 
                Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            System.out.println("Hello from reducer.");
    try{
            int[][] cellRideCounters = getCellRideCounters(values);
       if(cellRideCounter[0].length>0){ // control it before executing it. more explanation is above
            CellWithRideCount cellWithMostRides = 
                getCellWithMostRides(cellRideCounters);



            int[][] cellTotals = getCellTotals(values);
            CellWithTotalAmount cellWithGreatestTotal = 
                getCellWithGreatestTotal(cellTotals);

            String output = key + " "
                + cellWithMostRides.toString() + " "
                + cellWithGreatestTotal.toString();

            context.write(new Text(output), NullWritable.get());


     }
   }catch(Exception e)

    e.printstack();
     return;
   {

  }


}
```

- add try-catch to get exceptions in reduce function
- . Return from function in catch

. Also add an if statement before calling getCellWithMostRiders(..) I think the issue is in here. Fill the if statement as you want I made a guess and fill it according to my guess change it however you want if it is not proper for you

Comment: `System.out.println("Hello from reducer.");` never gets called, so I don't think the problem is in the reducer code.

Comment: do you have any "Cannot parse: " + recordString + "due to the " + ex);

Comment: No, i don't any other exception message either.

Comment: add if(recordString != null)  this statement beginning of your mapper, pickupHour might be null

Comment: Still no luck, all the records are in the correct format. Also note that the catch block in the mapper cathes everything, so if there are any exceptions, the mapper will just ignore the current line and move on.

Comment: what if map function throws one of them throws IOException, InterruptedException, delete this from map and also reduce and try again maybe?